# How to call arrows function in rpart.plot

Tags: r, nodes, decision-tree, rpart, arrows

I have to draw arrows with branches between two nodes in a decision tree

```
prp(ntree, type=4, extra=105, branch=0.8,
  box.col="grey", tweak=1.2,
  round=2, leaf.round =2, branch.lty=8, split.fun = split.fun, 
  faclen = 0, clip.facs = TRUE, 
  facsep = " or ", gap=0, space = 0, 
  arrows(x0, y0, x1, y1))
```

I want a graph like this one:

[image: Graph]

How to call arrows function in rpart.plot?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: prp(ntree, type=4, extra=105, branch=0.8,
     box.col="grey", tweak=1.2,
    round=2, leaf.round =2, branch.lty=8, split.fun = split.fun, 
    faclen = 0, clip.facs = TRUE, 
    facsep = " or ", gap=0, space = 0)

Comment: I want a graph like this.

Comment: Please edit your question to include code and data (don't add this info in comments because it can't be as nicely formatted).

Answer (score 0):

Arrows are not yet supported by `rpart.plot` (package version 3.0.9, Sep 2020).